# Python (Pandas) : When to use replace vs. map vs. transform?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clearly understand for which type of data transformation the following functions in pandas should be used:

- replace
- map
- transform

Can anybody provide some clear examples so I can better understand them?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Have you referred the Pandas document to know the difference?

Comment: Yes I have.I'm not asking what those functions do, I'm asking for which data transformation scenario we should use one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, Replace is used when working on missing values and transform is used while doing group_by operations.Map is used to change series or index