# replacing a column value in a dataframe using map and replace, the difference, using pandas

Tags: pandas

I can replace a couple of values in column, 'qualify', with true or false as follows and works just fine:

```
df['qualify'] = df['qualify'].map({'yes':True, 'np':False})
```

but if I use it  to change a name in another column, it will change the name but will make all other values in that column except the one it change to NaN.

```
df['name'] = df['name'].map({'dick':'Harry'})
```

Of course using replace will do the job right. But I need to understand why map() does not work correctly in the second instance?

```
df['name']=df['name'].replace('dick','Harry')
```

Comment: `map` changes the non-existing keys into `NaN`, while `replace` ignores them. That's expected behaviors.

Comment: great, I get it. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python (Pandas) : When to use replace vs. map vs. transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790392/python-pandas-when-to-use-replace-vs-map-vs-transform)